"Departure Date" for Freedom of Movement visa, when we intend to settle permanently
I am preparing to submit a "Freedom of Movement" Schengen visa application for my wife, a non-EU citizen. I am an EU citizen from an EU country other than the one we intend to visit, and therefore we can take advantage of the accelerated and free application procedure (per section 5.2 here).
This involves requesting a short-stay visa. I find this a confusing procedure because the stay will not be short at all. We intend to settle permanently and live together, as is our right.
This starts to become a problem when I am asked to provide the "Intended Date of Departure" on the application form. There isn't one.
So what should I enter here?

Our initial hotel reservation will only be for a few nights, after that we will be moving around a bit searching for a place for us to live. So should I enter a date matching the duration of the initial reservation?
On the other hand, this search will take some time (but definitely less than 90 days). Should I put in a date 90 days after the entry date, to cover the maximum amount of time that can pass before we get a permanent address and apply for my wife's residency card?
Or does none of this matter at all, and the visa officer will ignore the field?


Questions about permanent relocations are a better fit for [expatriates.se].

If you're filling out the paper form, you can write "none."  Are you filling out a paper form or is it a computer form that accepts only an actual date?

It's an online form and a departure date is required.

In that case I would probably put it at 90 days to avoid complications with the online form.


Our initial hotel reservation will only be for a few nights, after that we will be moving around a bit searching for a place for us to live. So should I enter a date matching the duration of the initial reservation?

I wouldn't do that and in fact I would not provide any details of the hotel reservation at all as this is explicitly not required for members of the family of an EU, EEA, or Swiss citizen. Getting a visa that's only valid for this period of time would also be annoying (not having a valid visa would not be enough to deny your application or force your wife out of the country but it could raise questions).

On the other hand, this search will take some time (but definitely less than 90 days). Should I put in a date 90 days after the entry date, to cover the maximum amount of time that can pass before we get a permanent address and apply for my wife's residency card?

That is exactly what I would recommend, mostly to prevent the consular officer from doing something stupid or getting confused and to ensure your wife's visa gives you as much flexibility as possible if you somehow need to leave and re-enter while you wait for the residence card. In all likelihood the consulate will be familiar with all this and will simply issue a multiple-entry visa valid for at least 6 months, as suggested by article 24(2) of the Schengen Visa Code but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Or does none of this matter at all, and the visa officer will ignore the field?

Indeed it shouldn't matter much, if at all. What matters is making it clear that this is an application for someone covered by the EU freedom of movement and documenting your marriage and citizenship precisely (a copy of the EU citizen's passport, potentially a translation, transcription, or apostille for the documents related to your marriage, depending on where it was registered). This is also why I would not fill in any field that's not required to avoid any confusion regarding the nature of the trip.
As long as you do that, the visa cannot legally be refused for any issues related to the duration or purpose of stay or any of the other standard reasons. The only relevant standard is whether the applicant is a threat to public safety, public health, or public policy. Such a refusal ought to be justified expressly and not merely using a canned reason on a refusal form so there is no way that a mistake in the intended date of departure field could lead to a refusal.

"Getting a visa that's only valid for this period of time...": The directive specifies that the visa is required only for entry, not to exercise the "right of residence for up to three months."

@phoog I had forgotten that and will remove the reference to a fine but either way nothing serious can happen and yet I think it's much more convenient to have a visa than not to have one.

Thanks for your very helpful answer! Regarding providing the reservation, I am required to prove that my wife is joining me. We will arrive separately, so the hotel reservation seems like the best choice for fulfilling this requirement. I saw something about providing a "sworn statement" instead, but I'm not sure what that means in practice. Would they just accept a letter from me? Or do I need to go to a notary?

Regarding reasons for rejection, there is one possibility that concerns me: the visa office can reject on the grounds that we have a "marriage of convenience". We only got married last month, which may raise a red flag. I intend to provide our photos and flight tickets from the last three years to defend against this.

@Artfunkel I don't think having married recently would be enough to refuse entry and the burden of proof is on the country who wants to deny you residence but you are right to focus on that, this is the most important point. I would not volunteer this information with the visa application but it's good to collect it if you need an appeal or your marriage is challenged during the rest of the procedure. I also see where you are coming from with the hotel reservation, travelling separately does complicate things a but but you can indeed write a letter spelling out the details.
